# Youtube data api V3 insert chat message error

Tags: youtube-data-api

I'm trying to insert messages into a live chat in a broadcast. I've used the tryout widget on [Google's API documentation page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveChatMessages/insert), and it works fine. I've supplied the following body:

```
{
    "snippet": {
       "liveChatId": "EiEKGFVDblhXWlgxUlNqWEdwMUlEWDBr[...]",
       "textMessageDetails": {
           "messageText": "Hello!"
       },
      "type": "textMessageEvent"
    }
}
```

I now tried to use the Python API:

```
>>> {
...   "snippet": {
...     "liveChatId": "EiEKGFVDblhXWlgxUlNqWEdwMUlEWDBr[...]",
...     "textMessageDetails": {
...       "messageText": "Hello"
...     },
...     "type": "textMessageEvent"
...   }
... }
>>> youtube.liveChatMessages().insert(part="snippet", body=body).execute()
```

But I'm getting:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveChat/messages?part=snippet&alt=json returned "snippet.text_message_details.message_text text is not valid.">
```

Any idea why this might occur? To me, the request seems identical to the one in the documentation, yet one works and the other doesn't.

Comment: I have this same problem. Did you ever figure out why it wasn't working for you?

Answer (score 1):

I was also stuck in this same problem. The solution of;

> ```
> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveChat/messages?part=snippet&alt=json returned "snippet.text_message_details.message_text text is not valid.">
> ```

is to just create your youtube channel first and then re-run this code. I hope it works for all.